# Getting the latest Tweet that isn't a direct message

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, tweets

I'm using [sferik's Twitter Gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) to grab the latest Tweet from a Twitter account using:

```
Twitter.user_timeline("someUserName").first.text
```

This works nicely but includes direct message Tweets. I would like to show the latest standard Tweet (i.e. not a Tweet @ someone).

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just played around a bit with the lib and it seems that even when there is a `@user` in the text the `to_user` property of the tweet is nil. A possible way to do it would be to simply search the text for occurrences of `@user` strings. For example like this:

```
tweets.find {|x| x.text.match(/@.*/) == nil }
```

Comment: Nice thinking. I'll give that a try. Although it is common to add @users later in an indirect Tweet so that these users are effectively cc'd, so this would reject those as well.

Comment: You can adjust the regex to only match @user at the beginning of the string.